# Wrapper for a standard STL-container

Tags: c++, collections

In the codebase I support, I found the following code. I am interested in your opinion about its expediency and especially the expediency of redefining the operator().

```
  template <typename KEY, typename VALUE>
  class MyUnorderedMap {
    std::unordered_map<KEY, VALUE> map;

  public:
    template <typename T>
    auto insert(const T value) {
      return map.insert(value);
    }
    inline auto& operator()(const KEY& r) { return (*this)[r]; }
    inline auto& operator[](const KEY r) { return map[r]; }
    inline auto find(const KEY& key) const { return map.find(key); }
    inline auto size() const { return map.size(); }
    inline auto begin() { return map.begin(); }
    inline auto end() { return map.end(); }

    inline bool exists(const KEY& userId) const {
      return map.find(userId) != map.end();
    }
    bool remove(const KEY& userId) {
      auto it = map.find(userId);
      bool retval = (it != map.end());
      if (retval)
        map.erase(it);
      return retval;
    }
  };
```

Comment: Welcome to [codereview.se]! It sounds like this is code you found rather than wrote yourself. Is that the case? If so I'm afraid this is off-topic because we only review code written by the user who posted the review question.

Comment: @Null this is kind of crazy, ok, this is my code. more precisely the code that I support

Comment: Perfectly valid thing to review.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I question the value of this template class.  We hide many important members of `std::unordered_map` (including `crbegin()`, `empty()`, `reserve()`, `at()`, `try_emplace()`) for no good reason.  The additional functions that are provided have no business being members: they are perfectly implementable as free functions without privileged access.

Considering the members in turn:

- `insert()`: only instantiable if `T` is convertible to the map's `value_type`.  Unnecessarily copies the argument.
- `operator()`: unnecessary, given that we have `operator[]`.
- `operator[]`: unnecessarily copies its argument.
- `find()`, `size()` `begin()`, `end()`: required only because the map is private.
- `exists()`: should be a free function.  If this is generic, why is the parameter called `userId`?
- `remove()` - why not just use the `erase()` that accepts a key?  Or do we have to build with pre-C++11 library?

---

When I've wanted to provide something like the `exists()` here, I've made it a standalone template function that can work with many kinds of container:

```
/*
 * contains()
 * A convenience overload that searches from beginning to end of a container.
 *
 * If an iterator is supplied, it will be written with the found position or
 * container.end() as appropriate.
 */
template<typename T, typename U>
inline bool contains(const T& container, const U& value)
{
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;
    return find(begin(container), end(container), value) != end;
}

template<typename T, typename U, typename Iter>
    /* Iter should be a T::iterator or T::const_iterator */
inline bool contains(T& container, const U& value, Iter& it)
{
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;
    return (it = find(begin(container), end(container), value)) != end;
}
```

```
/*
 * Overloads for pointer-to-const values within containers of pointer-to-mutable.
 */
template<typename T, typename U>
inline bool contains(const T& container, const U* value)
{
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;
    return find(begin(container), end(container), value) != end;
}

template<typename T, typename U, typename Iter>
inline bool contains(const T& container, const U* value, Iter& it)
{
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;
    return (it = find(begin(container), end(container), value)) != end;
}
```

```
/*
 * Overloads for maps (by key)
 */
template<typename T>
inline bool contains(const T& container, const typename T::key_type& key)
{
    return container.find(key) != container.end();
}

template<typename T, typename Iter>
inline bool contains(T& container, const typename T::key_type& key, Iter& it)
{
    return (it = container.find(key)) != container.end();
}

template<typename T>
inline bool contains(const T& container, const typename T::key_type& key,
                     typename T::mapped_type& result)
{
    typename T::const_iterator it;
    return contains(container, key, it) && (result = it->second, true);
}
```